# What does the "for stripe.com only" constraint of dj-stripe mean?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

https://github.com/pydanny/dj-stripe says, "For stripe.com only". I'm new enough to Stripe that I don't know what the implications of this are. What will I not be able to do as a result of using dj-stripe?

Comment: It means, this django library supports a wrapper for the stripe.com's api only, unlike other generic packages which support multiple payment mechanisms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means you won't be able to use dj-stripe with another payment processor like Braintree or PayPal.